# firefox href and onclick issues ,url gets updating on so many loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When I click a link on chrome its getting updated query string on address bar but URL gets updated on **Firefox** when I refresh the page so many times.

Following is the peace of code:

```
    var res1 ='<a href=\"#/test/" + nn.id + "\"
    onclick=\"window.location.reload()test</a>'\">   
    $('#cnt').append(res1);
```

Please suggest whats wrong with the **Firefox**.

Comment: for refreshing the page actually i need the updated info

Comment: @Satpal its creating issue in ff working fine on chrome

Comment: i have changed the logic to $(document).on('click', '.pk_cl', function(e) {

Comment: moved everything here still needs reloading to get updated url